# Python tkinter problem changing number of widgets when resizing window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program which displays a grid of widgets. When the window resizes horizontally,the widgets resize, but when the window resizes vertically, I want the height of the widgets to remain the same, but the number of rows to change. I had no luck with frame.bind("", configure), the window won't resize. root.after(1000, rsz) works, but if I make the delay much smaller, it does not. It just seems there should be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#def configure(event):
#    if not event.widget.master.master:
#        rsz()
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
def rsz():
    global lasth
    h = root.winfo_height()
    if h != lasth:
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        for row in range(int((h)/26)):
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=0)
            for col in range(6):
                frame.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
                ttk.Button(frame, text='row{}, col{}'.format(row,col)).grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='EWNS')
        lasth = h
    root.after(1000, rsz)
frame=tk.Frame(root,padx=5,pady=5)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NSEW")
lasth = -1
rsz()
#frame.bind("<Configure>", configure)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When i run your code the initial window loads with 18rows / 5 cols. When i use the maximise window button it loads 38rows / col count remains the same..is that what your after?? Im not sure I totally understand your issue

Comment: That is the behavior I want. Resizing the window by dragging the bottom bar works with the occasional glitch. If you change the delay in the root.after to 100, it doesn't work at all. I would like something that always works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

`rsz()` should work fine with `frame.bind('<Configure>')`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

lasth = -1

def rsz(event):
    global lasth
    #h = root.winfo_height()
    h = event.height
    if h != lasth:
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        for row in range(h//26):
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
            for col in range(6):
                ttk.Button(frame, text='row{}, col{}'.format(row,col)).grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='nsew')
        lasth = h

frame=tk.Frame(root, padx=5, pady=5)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
# since number of columns does not change
# grid_columnconfigure() can be called once for each column
for col in range(6):
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
frame.bind("<Configure>", rsz)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: On windows 10, I can't use the mouse to resize the window by dragging the top or bottom bar. Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have that issue.

Comment: So when you put the mouse over the bottom edge and the double arrow cursor shows, you can click and drag and change the height. I've tried on my Windows 10 machine with Python 3.7.5 and an old Windows 7 machine and on neither can I click and drag to resize. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: Then I don't know why.